# Is there faster way about javascript autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**Goal** : faster way autocomplete

**Situation**: I use vue js, when open the page, execute in mounted()

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/games/all')
         .then(res=>{
              this.$store.state.games = res.data;
              this.$store.dispatch('GetGames',res.data);
         })
         .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

axios get games/all is

```
router.get('/all',(req,res,next)=>{
  let responseData = {};
  Game.find({},(err,rows)=>{
      if(err) throw err;
      if(rows.length) {
          responseData.result = 1;
          responseData.data = rows;
      }else{
          responseData.result = 0;
      }
      res.json(responseData.data);
    //   console.log(responseData.data);
  });
})
```

I got a json file like

```
{
    { gamename:"agricola",
      maxplayer:4,
      minplayer:1,
      mintime:20,
      maxtime:90,
      difficulty:"hard",
    }
}
```

There are 200~300 columns.

Using vuex

```
state: {
    games:"",
  },
mutations: {
    getGames(state,payload){
      state.games = payload;
      console.log("받아온 게임",state.games);
    },
}
GetGames:({commit},payload)=>{
      commit('getGames',payload)
    },
```

When I bring db, using state in store.js file, so I use autocomplete

```
 const autocomplete = document.querySelector(".autocomplete");
      if (this.gameInput) {
        this.result = this.games.filter((game) => {
          return game.gamename.match(new RegExp(this.gameInput, "i"))
        });
      } else {
        autocomplete.classList.add("disabled");
      }
```

the gameInput is your typing

**Problem**: it takes too long to bring the DB (4000ms~) and Data is stored in local storage. Even after receiving the data, I cannot search unless refresh it. so user has to stay until bring the db, and user cannot search game until refresh the page. I want they don't need to refresh my page. thanks for read my question. sorry about my poor English (tear)

Comment: I don't understand why the user has to refresh the page? Just a tip: move your API Call from mounted to created. This Lifecycle runs before, so why do you want to wait if your DOM is rendered. Makes no sense  (I know it's in the doc). It'll give you some milliseconds.

Comment: It might be faster to send the search request to the backend and return results (which can be cached to make the request return faster). As you now understand yourself, it is much overhead for the frontend to handle all the data.